# spring hateoas linkTo method with withSelfRel() not working when spring controller method mapped with multiple path values

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, hateoas, spring-hateoas

I am facing issue when Spring controller method having multiple path values while using Hateoas linkTo to get the links

Spring controller method is as follows

`

```
@RestController`enter code here`
@RequestMapping("/northwindmodel.svc")
@ExposesResourceFor(Category.class)
public class CategoryController {
@RequestMapping(value = **{"/Categories({categoryID})","/Categories(CategoryID={categoryID}"}**, method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json, application/xml", produces = { "application/json" })
    public ResponseEntity<Result> read(@PathVariable(value ="categoryID")Integer categoryID)  throws NoRecordFoundException{
        Category category = this.getService().read(categoryID);
        return new ResponseEntity<Result>(new Result(getAssembler().toResource(category) ),HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

`

Resource Assembler method for link

`Link link = linkTo(methodOn(CategoryController.class).read(categoryID)).withSelfRel();`

as controller read method has two paths as 
1./Categories({categoryID})
2./Categories(CategoryID={categoryID}

I think linkTo method is unable to decide which path to pick and failing with error as

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple method level mappings defined on method public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity`

can somebody please help me in this issue?

Thanks
-Trim

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect.

Comment: @zeroflagL,I am working on spring mvc project  with Hateoas for REST resource links.with single request path value(in controller method), Hateoas Link working fine.but for multiple request paths failing.so I am looking for fix that works when multiple path values present in controller method.

Answer (score 1):

resolved this issue by upgrading hateoas lib to 0.20 from 0.16

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
            <version>0.20.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Hi, I am also facing similar issue. In my case i want the 2nd value path, but i always get the first value path in the self link (I dont get the exception, as i am using this above mentioned dependency). Do you have any idea how can this be achieved.